# Is "in" necessary in "share [in] my joy"?

Tags: prepositions

What difference does "in" make in the following? Is it optional?

> He can share [in] my joy and sorrow.

Comment: I would say yes, it is optional. The meaning is the same either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there is a very slight meaning difference: to *share in* someone's joy means to involve oneself emotionally in a joyful situation that primarily/directly affects someone else. For example, if person A has a baby, and person B feels close to person A, it would be natural to say that person B *shares in* person A's joy.

To *share* someone's joy is more neutral—it means to also feel joyful (likely for the same reason).

Answer (score 2):

The preposition ***in*** is optional between the verb ***share*** and nouns referring to mental states such as ***joy, sorrow, pain,...*** (this doesn't affect the *meaning*). But it's [usually *not* included...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=share%20your%20pain%2Cshare%20in%20your%20pain%2Cshare%20your%20joy%2Cshare%20in%20your%20joy&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10)

[image]

Note - for the near-synonymous *I **feel** your joy, sorrow, pain,...* the preposition is ***never*** included.